# Scala template how to loop over two lists simultaneously

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

i have two lists

```
 cards=List[Card]
 paymentMode=List[String]
```

i want to loop over them simultaneously in Twirl template engine (Play Framework)
i tried

```
(cards zip paymentMode).map{ case (card, p) =>
```

and when i call `@card` i got "not found: value card"

Comment: Please post your actual code, formatted (curly braces button)

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets first look at Scala and then Twirl. So you have we have two lists:

```
scala> val cards: List[String] = List("a", "b", "c")
cards: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val paymentMethods: List[String] = List("visa", "master", "debit")
paymentMethods: List[String] = List(visa, master, debit)
```

Then zip them together (I assume lists are with the same length):

```
scala> cards.zip(paymentMethods)
res0: List[(String, String)] = List((a,visa), (b,master), (c,debit)
```

After this you can have a for loop to go through it:

```
scala> for((c,p) <- res0){println(s"The card $c with payment $p")}
The card a with payment visa
The card b with payment master
The card c with payment debit
```

**In Twirl**: In your views you can have something like the following (make note on how to define a val and use a for loop and how I use `@` as escape character or as a reference):

```
@cards = @{List("a", "b", "c")}
@paymentMethods = @{List("visa", "master", "debit")}
@zipCardsPayments = @{cards.zip(paymentMethods)}

@for((c, p) <- zipCardsPayments){
  <h3> card: @c with methods: @p</h3>
}
```

And the following is the output I'm getting within in the browser:

[image]